# My minecraft is borked

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A (longish) time ago, back before 1.10, I could see the coordinates, block ID, and biome from my Minecraft's F3 debug screen.

And then the malware came. I ended up reverting to a backup three times to delete it. (Sometime after that fiasco, I tried getting on a heavily modded server, the downloading of the proper mods and Forge seemingly being the cause of the second problem).

My problem is now twofold. The only way I can open Minecraft is through the launcher.jar file (Minecraft.exe, Feed the Beast, and TechnicLauncher do not open anything. Ever since I went on that server that one time, I am now no longer able to see my coordinates or the block I'm looking at.

How do I fix this? Should I uninstall? (How do I uninstall? I'd need to remove every file related to Minecraft from my computer).

I would love to know what block I'm standing on again, and what block I'm mining. After all, surprise Silverfish are a horrible fate...

Comment: I don't think the problem is with Minecraft here. If you got malware that affected MC, that's the problem.

Comment: By chance, when you do F3, does CTRL+F3 or SHIFT+F3 work?  I believe the dev stats was changed around to be harder to find?

Comment: I'm not concerned about the dev stats, and the malware's entirely gone. I want to be able to see coordinates, and none of those key combos work at giving me coords.

Answer (score 3):

Just rename your .minecraft folder to something else, anything will work, and redownload the installer from the minecraft.net website. This should reinstall the game.

All of your worlds/servers/mods are in the .minecraft folder you renamed and can be easily copied to the new one.

Comment: This is the best way to start troubleshooting the issue. If Minecraft works fine using a clean .minecraft folder, then it's possible something in the original .jar is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have reduced debug info activated. (It would have been helpful to see a screenshot of your F3 screen, though.) With reduced debug info the F3 screen will not show any positional information like coordinates of player, coordinates of block you are looking at or the direction and angle you are looking at.

You can toggle reduced debug info in "Options" > "Chat Settings" by clicking on "Reduced Debug Info: ON/OFF". This setting can be enforced by certain servers, though, so if a server decides to withhold the coordinates from a player your game will have reduced debug info activated for as long as you are on this certain server. It should be automatically deactivated afterwards, though.